# Why my SSD is showing different amount of space in different apps?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I have a Samsung SSD 750 Evo 250 GB but not all disk managers are showing the same capacity, even between partitions already created.

[image: Different managers screenshot]

I don't know if is need it but I have:

Intel i3-6100

8 GB RAM

Radeon RX 460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a difference in units.

**GiB** stands for Gibibytes: 1GiB = 1024MiB.

**GB** stands for Gigabytes: 1GB = 1000MB.

1 gibibyte ≈ 1.074 gigabytes.

Therefore, 209.76GiB ≈ 225.28GB

[See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)

Comment: for more about this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix