# Missing disk space after repartiotioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, disk

So I have 512 gb ssd and in Gparted my main partition in the size of 476g and the efi partition of 512mb,
I had a crash I couldn't fix yesterday so I reinstalled Ubuntu in a new partition, moved the files to the new installation, deleted the old partition and resized the partition to the maximum size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any missing space, are you talking about the difference between `GiB` and `GB`?

Comment: @mook765 I see a difference of 36 between the actual disk size of 512, and the ext4 partition, I don't see where the 36GB are...

Comment: I would tend to say that your question has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/819042/590937).

Comment: @mook765, silly me, thank you!

Comment: Also, if you look at how GParted shows this disk, the sizes are consistent: It shows your disk as "476.94 GiB". Disk manufacturers try to make their products better than they really are, using those misleading 1000-based units that have not been any standard for storage ever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my SSD is showing different amount of space in different apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819042/why-my-ssd-is-showing-different-amount-of-space-in-different-apps)